# Visual studio code debug tool for python unit test does not show debug tools, when extra library is imported

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, visual-studio-code

For pure Django tests, visual studio code easily discovers my tests so i can debug them:

```py
from django.test import TestCase


class SomethingTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        return super().setUp()

    def test_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, 4)
```

But when i add some Django-rest-framework libraries - debug tools disappear:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

class BoringTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        return super().setUp()

    def test_boring(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, 4)
```

How can I setup vs code unit-test debug tools so i can use rest_framework?